# SHM oil tanker + jumping mouse forcing, solving equations of motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A large oil tanker of mass $W$ floats on the sea of density $ρ$. Suppose the tanker is given a small downward displacement $z$. The upward force is equal to the weight of water displaced (Archimedes’ Principle). If the cross-sectional area $A$ of the tanker at the water surface is constant, show that this upward force is $gρAz$, and hence that

$\ddot{z} + \frac{gρA}{W}z = 0$.

Suppose now that a mouse exercises on the deck of the tanker producing a vertical force $m\sin ωt$, where $ω = (gρA/W)^{1/2}$. Show that the tanker will eventually sink.
Taken from https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/IA_M/differential_equations_eg.pdf (Sheet 3 question 9)

---

For the final part, the forcing term is part of the complementary function so using detuning gives particular integral

$z_p = \frac{-t}{2\omega}\cos\omega t$

The only initial condition we have is presumably $z=0$ at $t=0$ and so I'm getting

$z = A\sin\omega t - \frac{t}{2\omega}\cos\omega t$

which seems wrong because although it would "sink", sort of, every time the cosine term became negative for large $t$ it would also be hurling itself into the sky!?

Comment: What happened to the $m$ - did it cancel somewhere?

Comment: The solution is wrong. $A$ is area, so you should use a different letter. But then $t/\omega$ has units of second$^2$. Beside this, the solution is valid only until the ship either sinks or gets completely to the surface. In both those cases, the Archimedes' law does not applies if you write the volume as area times amplitude of oscillation

Comment: The units in the question seem a bit suspect as well. Is $m$ meant to be the weight of the mouse?

Comment: David - I'm wondering if the question is supposed to have $W$ as weight rather than mass. I made a mistake assuming $W=mg$ and $m$ would cancel which seemed to be the way the question was contrived.

Comment: Andrei - Where could the error in units have come from? I used the procedure for detuning outlined on the bottom of page 34 here - https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/IA_M/differential_equations.pdf - is this incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Solving the movement with forcing function, we have

$$
\ddot z(t)+\omega_0^2z(t)-m \sin \left(\omega_0t\right)=0
$$

calculating the Laplace transform

$$
\left(s^2+\omega_0^2\right)\hat z(s) - \frac{m\omega_0}{s^2+\omega_0^2} = sz_0+\dot z_0
$$

and then

$$
\hat z(s) = \frac{m\omega_0}{\left(s^2+\omega_0^2\right)^2}+\frac{sz_0+\dot z_0}{s^2+\omega_0^2}
$$

Now supposing null initial conditions

$$
\hat z(s) = \frac{m\omega_0}{\left(s^2+\omega_0^2\right)^2}
$$

Observe that we have a double pair of poles in $\hat z(s)$. Now inverting we have

$$
z(t) = \frac{m}{2\omega_0^2}\left(\sin(\omega_0t)-\omega_0\cos(\omega_0 t)t\right)
$$

and persisting the forcing action, the amplitude of $z(t)$ grows with $t$.